# How to remove unchecked assignment warning in hibernate generics

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I am implementing the generics to access the data in hibernate using following code:

```
public static <T> List<T> get(Class<T> clazz,Map map) throws GenericDataAccessException {
        List<T> data = null;
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtilities.getSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(clazz.getName());
            Iterator itr  = map.entrySet().iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                Map.Entry entry = ( Map.Entry)itr.next();
                cr.add(Restrictions.eq(entry.getKey().toString(),entry.getValue()));
            }
            data = cr.list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("Hibernate Error::" +  e.toString());
            throw new GenericDataAccessException(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if(session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

But at the line `data = cr.list();` unchecked assignment warning is shown. How remove this warning without suppress warning ?
If I change the return type from generic list to list then warning is removed but in that case I  get the warning in class from where calling this method.

Comment: You can put `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` above your `get()` method.  But keep in mind if there is a warning, you may very well have an error at runtime.  So really your question is twofold: how to disable the warning, and how to cope with the potential ensuing error.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen thanks for reply but I don't  want to suppress warning  I want to handle it with my code implementation. Is there is any other way so I can implement this  method without warning?

Comment: If you want to do that, you need to have a proper generic type for everything you mention in your method, including `Map`, `Iterator`, and `Map.Entry`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman thanks. But here map and iterator is used only for set criteria and restriction then how it will affect the return type of cr.list() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there are some problems in your code

1. You don't commit and rollback a transaction.
2. You don't need to log an exception in a low level method, just rethrow it.
3. If you log an exception you should do it this way

   `logger.debug("Hibernate Error", e);`
4. You should rethrow an exception this way

   `throw new GenericDataAccessException(e);`
5. You don't need `data` just do

   `return cr.list();`

There is no way to remove an "unchecked assignment" warning, because of `Criteria` has a `list()` declaration with return type `List` not `List<?>`.

```
List list() throws HibernateException;
```

So just use suggested by  @TimBiegeleisen `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. But only in one low level place! Not above all kinds of `get()` methods. So you need to have a more complex architecture of your generics with one `get()` method.

- Firstly, you can separate working with a session and transactions in the separate utility method. Something like this 
  [HibernateSessionFactory#doInTransaction()](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/factory/HibernateSessionFactory.java#L41).
- The second step is configure request parameters outside a request method (something likes your `map`) like this [HibernateRequest#list()](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/request/HibernateRequest.java#L267).